# CSS is not working when redirecting with htaccess

Tags: css, .htaccess

For some reason, my CSS won't work when I just go to index, but if I go to **index.php** it works perfectly fine.

[image: what happens]

This is the code inside my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewrite Cond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: check your chrome or browser console what path are coming for css/js files

Comment: Please include all information directly in your questions. Links to pictures or other external resources are _not_ a replacement for that and considered by style there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the URL **mrglad.tv/index** (without the trailing "/" after index). I think the browser is attempting to load the CSS from a path relative to **/index/** on the server rather than relative to the root of **mrglad.tv/**